# Share documents with users without permission

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, share

I have the following case: There are 2 departments with each having a separate site collection with a document library. Only the users from a department have access to the corresponding site collection and library. What is the best practice to let a user share a document from department X with a person from department Y without changing the permissions on the libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing permissions, the only way would perhaps be to create one additional site collection, call it "Sharing" or something similar, and instruct people to copy shared documents there OR create them there in the first place.